# Button enabled from 3 condition

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the button to be enabled only when all three condition are met which are at least one checkbox is selected in the 1st checkbox list and 2nd checkbox selected and option list selected.

For the 1st condition i was thinking as an alternative would javascript be able to check on strlen of the textbox ?

Somehow the pure javascript below is not working and would it be possible if selection by the user goes in reverse ?

Pure javascript:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById('termsChkbx').addEventListener("change", function(){
      this.parentNode.style.color = this.checked ? "black" : "red";
    }, false);
});

function change(obj) {

        var selectBox = obj;
        var selected = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
        var retCustDetails = document.getElementById("retCustDetails");
        var tradeCustDetails = document.getElementById("tradeCustDetails");

        if(selected === 'ret'){
            retCustDetails.style.display = "block";
            tradeCustDetails.style.display = "none";
        }
        else if (selected === 'trd') {
            retCustDetails.style.display = "none";
            tradeCustDetails.style.display = "block";
        }
        else if  (selected === '') {
            retCustDetails.style.display = "none";
            tradeCustDetails.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function isChecked() {
  var sum = 0; //store a running sum

  //find all price elements: class "CDPrice" within element of class "item"
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".item .CDPrice"), function(item) {
    //get the corresponding checkbox
    var chosen = item.parentElement.querySelector('[type="checkbox"]');

    //if checked, add to the running sum
    if (chosen.checked) {
      var value = parseFloat(item.innerHTML) || 0; //if parseFloat() returns none, default value to zero
      sum += value;
    }
  });

  //update the total
  var total = document.getElementById("total");
  total.value = sum.toFixed(2);
}    

function Checked() {
var checkedRadioButtons = document.querySelector('[name="deliveryType"]:checked');
document.getElementById("total").value = checkedRadioButtons.getAttribute("title");

}


//conditions for submit button to be enable
//var firstCondition = document.querySelectorAll('name=CDPrice');
//var termsCheckbox = document.getElementById('termsChkbx');
var show = document.getElementById('show');
var button = document.getElementById('sub1');

var conditions = {
//  cond1: false,
//  cond2: false,
  cond3: false
};

//function setCondition1(e) {
//  conditions.cond1 = e.target.checked;
//  enableButton(conditions);
//}

//function setCondition2(e) {
//  conditions.cond2 = e.target.checked;
//  enableButton(conditions);
//}

function setCondition3(e) {
  conditions.cond3 = e.target.value && e.target.value.length > 0;
  enableButton(conditions);
}

function enableButton(options) {
  if (options.cond3) {
    button.removeAttribute('disabled');
  } else {
    button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  }
}

//for(i=0 ; i< firstCondition.length ; i++){
//  firstCondition[i].addEventListener("click", setCondition1, false);
//}
//termsCheckbox.addEventListener('change', setCondition2, false);
show.addEventListener('change', setCondition3, false);

</script>
```

1st condition -> Checkbox list or textbox:

```
<?php
include_once('database_conn.php');
$sqlCDs = 'SELECT CDID, CDTitle, CDYear, catDesc, CDPrice FROM nmc_cd b inner join nmc_category c on b.catID = c.catID WHERE 1 order by CDTitle';
$rsCDs = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlCDs);
while ($CD = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsCDs)) {
    echo "\t<div class='item'>
            <span class='CDTitle'>{$CD['CDTitle']}</span>
            <span class='CDYear'>{$CD['CDYear']}</span>
            <span class='catDesc'>{$CD['catDesc']}</span>
            <span class='CDPrice'>{$CD['CDPrice']}</span>
            <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='CD[]' value='{$CD['CDID']}' title='{$CD['CDPrice']}'onchange='isChecked();'/></span>
        </div>\n";
}
?>


<section id="checkCost">
            <h2>Total cost</h2>
            Total <input type="text" name="total" id="total" size="10" readonly="readonly" />
        </section>
```

2nd condition -> 2nd checkbox:

```
<p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
            <input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx" onchange="isChecked(this,'sub1')"/></p>
```

3rd condition -> Option List:

```
<section id="placeOrder">
            <h2>Place order</h2>
            Your details
            Customer Type: <select id="show" name="customerType" onchange="change(this)">
                <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
                <option value="ret">Customer</option>
                <option value="trd">Trade</option>
            </select>
```

Submit Button:

```
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order now!" id="sub1" disabled="disabled"/></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach event listeners on each input and listen for changes.

```
var firstCondition = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="testName"]');
var termsCheckbox = document.getElementById('termsChkbx');
var show = document.getElementById('show');
var button = document.getElementById('sub1');
```

Object to hold all the conditions

```
var conditions = {
  cond1: false,
  cond2: false,
  cond3: false
}
```

Declared functions to use with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```
function setCondition1(e) {
  conditions.cond1 = e.target.checked;
  enableButton(conditions);
}

function setCondition2(e) {
  conditions.cond2 = e.target.checked;
  enableButton(conditions);
}

function setCondition3(e) {
  conditions.cond3 = e.target.value && e.target.value.length > 0;
  enableButton(conditions);
}
```

Enable button

```
function enableButton(options) {
  if (options.cond1 && options.cond2 && options.cond3) {
    button.removeAttribute('disabled');
  } else {
    button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  }
}
```

Add event listeners

```
for(i=0 ; i< firstCondition.length ; i++){
  firstCondition[i].addEventListener("click", setCondition1, false);
}
termsCheckbox.addEventListener('change', setCondition2, false);
show.addEventListener('change', setCondition3, false);
```

**example:** http://jsfiddle.net/qjo9rqgc/

Comment: Thanks, I'm not able to figure out where did "e" come from ? and may i ask because you declare name="testName" inside your input, can i use 'CDPrice' ?

Comment: @DLum `e` is from the event passed when you `click` from the MDN docs __listener: 
The object that receives a notification when an event of the specified type occurs. This must be an object implementing the EventListener interface, or simply a JavaScript function.__

Comment: Hmm... still not able to understand that.. I try to look at it again.. for the event listener for 1st condition, can i use ".item .CDPrice" ?

Comment: I don't understand... i try to test with only 1 condition and neither does any work..I try removing from within the if statement -> if (options.cond1 && options.cond2 && options.cond3)

Comment: @DLum yes you can use `name=CDPrice`. The first condition selects all the input with `[name='testName']` but you can change the selector to fit your needs. I was also assuming that there will be plenty of checkboxes for the firstCondition so I iterated an array. You can use `addEventListener` on any `EventTarget` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget

Comment: Thank you, I was able to re-run your codes on jsfiddle changing the conditions .. I updated the question on pure javascript.. wondering if there's other JavaScript code that's conflicting with this